# Does Malloc only use the heap if requested memory space is large?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc, heap-memory

Whenever you study the memory allocation of processes you usually see it outlined like this:

[image]

So far so good.

But then you have the sbrk() system call which allows the program to change the upper limit of its **data section**, and it can also be used to simply check where that limit is with sbrk(0). Using that function I found the following patterns:

**Pattern 1 - Small malloc**

I run the following program on my Linux machine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int globalVar;

int main(){
        int localVar;
        int *ptr;

        printf("localVar address (i.e., stack) = %p\n",&localVar);
        printf("globalVar address (i.e., data section) = %p\n",&globalVar);
        printf("Limit of data section = %p\n",sbrk(0));

        ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*1000);

        printf("ptr address (should be on stack)= %p\n",&ptr);
        printf("ptr points to: %p\n",ptr);
        printf("Limit of data section after malloc= %p\n",sbrk(0));

        return 0;
}
```

And the output is the following:

```
localVar address (i.e., stack) = 0xbfe34058
globalVar address (i.e., data section) = 0x804a024
Limit of data section = 0x91d9000
ptr address (should be on stack)= 0xbfe3405c
ptr points to: 0x91d9008
Limit of data section after malloc= 0x91fa000
```

As you can see the allocated memory region was right above the old data section limit, and after the malloc that limit was pushed upward, so the allocated region is actually inside the new data section.

**Question 1**: Does this mean that small mallocs will allocate memory in the data section and not use the heap at all?

**Pattern 2 - Big Malloc**

If you increase the requested memory size on line 15:

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*100000);
```

you will now the following output:

```
localVar address (i.e., stack) = 0xbf93ba68
globalVar address (i.e., data section) = 0x804a024
Limit of data section = 0x8b16000
ptr address (should be on stack)= 0xbf93ba6c
ptr points to: 0xb750b008
Limit of data section after malloc= 0x8b16000
```

As you can see here the limit of the data section has not changed, and instead the allocated memory region is in the middle of the gap section, between the data section and the stack.

**Question 2**: Is this the large malloc actually using the heap?

**Question 3**: Any explanation for this behavior? I find it a bit insecure, cause on the first example (small malloc) even after you free the allocated memory you'll still be able to use the pointer and use that memory without getting a seg fault, as it will be inside your data section, and this could lead to hard to detect bugs.

**Update with Specs**: Ubuntu 12.04, 32-bits, gcc version 4.6.3, Linux kernel 3.2.0-54-generic-pae.

Update 2: Rodrigo's answer below solved this mystery. [This Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) also helped.

Comment: All of these "will stuff X happen if stuff Y happens" questions are theoretical and practically unanswerable without mentioning a specific implementation. What Linux? Which compiler? Which standard library implementation? What CPU?

Comment: @H2CO3, so are you saying you are sure the above behavior is implementation-dependent and not standard of the Linux kernel, for instance? Cause if this was standard of the Linux kernel then specs wouldn't matter right? Either way I included them for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Thanks. Since the behavior you are asking about is not specified by the C standard, the underlying implementation is free to do whatever it wants. Of course, the Kernel's documentation does matter, but I'd anticipate that at least the used standard library implementation matters as well, not to mention Linuxes that run on a different, more "exotic" architecture than the ones you'd "intuitively" expect as exclusive hosts (microcontrollers with no heap, anyone?). (Now I've upvoted because this is otherwise a good question.)

Comment: @H2CO3 I agree. I find the behavior curious nonetheless (don't you?), so let's see if someone has more clues about it.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding `sbrk()`. It is only telling you the point up to which you have "allocated" memory on the heap. It is actually on the heap as far as I understand it.

Comment: @DanielS Of course I do, let's wait for some answers (unfortunately I can't answer this...)

Comment: @nonsencikle, that's not what Wikipedia or the Linux man page says about the function. Quoting the man page: "brk, sbrk - change data segment size".

Comment: This http://www.inf.udec.cl/~leo/Malloc_tutorial.pdf is where I learned about `malloc` and it suggests that `sbrk()` merely states which part of the heap belongs to you and which part does not. Section 2.1

Comment: @nonsencikle I don't think that is correct, and you can even test this. In fact see my "second pattern" example, with the big malloc. You'll notice sbrk(0) there returns an address much lower then the section you have allocated with malloc, so it's not related to the heap.

Comment: My understanding is that `malloc` does memory management of heap in user space - freeing or requesting chunks of memory from the OS as required (i.e. trying to reduce expensive context switches). I also think that malloc does request chunks of memory that is capitable with that OS/hardward.

Comment: Keep in mind that many heap managers will place extremely large allocations (generally over 16M or so) in a different "segment" from the rest, with a visibly different set of high-order bits in the address.  And it's not unusual for stack and heap to be in different segments.  The above diagram is pleasantly simple and concise (and a good conceptual view) but often doesn't reflect reality.

Comment: @Hot Licks, are you talking about virtual or physical memory? The diagram above is used to illustrate how virtual memory of processes will work, while we know that physical pages/segments can be all over the place and the hardware/OS will manage that.

Comment: It seems I was beaten to it by @rodrigo but yeah, I agree that `mmap` is the culprit for your case 2.

Comment: @DanielS - The entire possible virtual memory space for a process is rarely allocated.  Rather, it'd divided up into segments of 16M to 1G or so, and the segments are "mapped" as the process requests new allocations.  In some cases an entire segment may be allocated to satisfy one (massive) malloc request.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, the only way to be absolutely sure of what happens is to read the source code of `malloc`. Or even better, step through it with the debugger.

But anyway, here are my understanding of these things:

1. The system call `sbrk()` is used to increase the size of the data section, all right. Usually, you will not call it directly, but it will be called by the *implementation* of `malloc()` to increase the memory available for the heap.
2. The function `malloc()` does not allocate memory from the OS. It just splits the data section in pieces and assigns these pieces to whoever need them. You use `free()` to mark one piece as unused and available for reassignment.
3. Point 2 is an oversimplification. At least the GCC implementation, for big blocks, `malloc()` allocates them using `mmap()` with private, non-file backed options. Thus, these blocks are outside of the data segment. Obviously, calling `free()` in such a block will call `munmap()`.

What is exactly a *big block* depends on many details. See `man mallopt` for the gory details.

From that, you can guess what happens when you access to free'd memory:

1. If the block was *small*, the memory will still be there, so if you read nothing will happen. If you write to it, you may corrupt the internal heap structures, or it may have been reused and you can corrupt any random structure.
2. If the block was big, the memory has been unmapped, so any access will result in a segmentation fault. Unless the improbable situation that in the interim, another big block is allocated (or another thread calls `mmap()` and the same address range happen to be used.

**Clarification**

The term *data section* is used with two different meanings, depending on the context.

1. The `.data` section of the executable (linker point of view). It may also include `.bss` or even `.rdata`. For the OS that means nothing, it just maps pieces of the program into memory with little regard of what it contains other than the flags (read-only, executable...).
2. The *heap*, that block of memory that every process has, that is not read from the executable, and that can be grown using `sbrk()`.

You can see that with the following command that prints the memory layout of a simple program (`cat`):

```
$ cat /proc/self/maps
08048000-08053000 r-xp 00000000 00:0f 1821106    /usr/bin/cat
08053000-08054000 r--p 0000a000 00:0f 1821106    /usr/bin/cat
08054000-08055000 rw-p 0000b000 00:0f 1821106    /usr/bin/cat
09152000-09173000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b73df000-b75a5000 r--p 00000000 00:0f 2241249    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
b75a5000-b75a6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b75a6000-b774f000 r-xp 00000000 00:0f 2240939    /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so
b774f000-b7750000 ---p 001a9000 00:0f 2240939    /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so
b7750000-b7752000 r--p 001a9000 00:0f 2240939    /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so
b7752000-b7753000 rw-p 001ab000 00:0f 2240939    /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so
b7753000-b7756000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7781000-b7782000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7782000-b7783000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b7783000-b77a3000 r-xp 00000000 00:0f 2240927    /usr/lib/ld-2.18.so
b77a3000-b77a4000 r--p 0001f000 00:0f 2240927    /usr/lib/ld-2.18.so
b77a4000-b77a5000 rw-p 00020000 00:0f 2240927    /usr/lib/ld-2.18.so
bfba0000-bfbc1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

The first line is the executable code (`.text` section).

The second line is the read-only data (`.rdata` section) and some other read-only sections.

The third line is the `.data` + `.bss` and some other writable sections.

The fourth line is the heap!

The next lines, those with a name are memory mapped files or shared objects. Those without a name are probably big malloc'ed blocks of memory (or maybe private anonymous mmap's, they are impossible to distinguish).

The last line is the stack!

Comment: In point 1 you say that sbrk() is used to increase size of "data section", but that the sbrk() function is called by malloc() to increase the memory available "for the heap". So it's not clear. Are you saying sbrk() acts on the data section or on the heap? Or are you saying they are the same thing under a practical point of view?

Comment: Also, do you you agree with could then say that the "heap" is when you allocate via mmap() for big chunks of memory, and that for small chunks the "heap" will not be used but rather the "data section"?

Comment: @DanielS: Sorry, I was not very clear. Please, see my added example.

Comment: @DanielS: No! The heap is the block of memory used by `malloc` for small blocks, and it is also the data structure used to manage those blocks. `mmap()` uses simply _unallocated space_, and the structures used to manage those are in the kernel VMM. Also, note that the heap structure is totally implemented in user-space library code.

Comment: gotcha, and makes sense now. So when the man page of sbrk() talks about "data section" it's actually talking about the "heap" right? And sbrk(0) indeed returns the top of the heap? I was confusing with the executable file data section indeed. Now it makes sense, either the malloc allocated on the heap, or if too large it allocates via mmpa(). Is this correct now?

Comment: @DanielS: Yeah, you got it! I'm guessing that the confusion about the term _data section_ may come from the good old days, when the executable was loaded into memory in a single big block, and the heap was actually a prolongation of that block, very much like the diagram from your question.